# How to invoke gcloud with service account impersonation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-oauth

I have a service running in GCE with default service account A. This service uses gcloud to talk to various GCP services. Currently, it uses service account B to talk to some of the GCP services (using private key). However, we want to get rid of using private key and use account impersonation. To do that, I have added account A to the service account B's role and given token creator role.

I wrote a test program in go and was able to verify the impersonation works. However, our service is in PHP, and uses gcloud SDK. I couldn't find a way to configure gcloud to impersonate a service account or provide custom token.

One option is that I rewrite all the gcloud code to use google SDK, but that is lots of work, and I'd rather avoid that. My question is, how do I invoke gcloud using service account B in this scenario?. Is there a way to pass access token to gcloud or specify impersonation user?

Answer (score 11):

`gcloud` has a `--impersonate-service-account` flag for this.

Comment: I found the example in this [YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHdQ13HSCq8) useful.

sample command

`gcloud compute instances create made-by-impersonation --impersonate-service-account=fun-with-impersonation@my-project-sa.iam.gserviceaccount.com `

Answer (score 9):

1. Run `gcloud auth login` and login using your gcp email address.
2. Run `export GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account=<sa-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com)` command to generate temporary credentials from the service account and store as the current OAUTH token. (this  OAUTH token only lasts for 1 hour so make sure the operation using this token can complete within that time frame.

Comment: For this to succeed, make sure to give yourself the *Service Account Token Creator* (`roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`) IAM role

Answer (score 2):

In my example running an app on Cloud Run, i had to set the audiences:

```
export TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token --impersonate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --audiences='AUDIENCE')

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" ENDPOINT
```